# How to keep the selected checkboxes checked while pagination?

Tags: php, jquery, session, checkbox, pagination

new to Laravel. Using 5.3 and loving it. Having a problem with my checkboxes while pagination. I want to keep the selected checkboxes checked while pagination. Is there any way using 'appends' or 'session' or something else. Codes until now is provided below.

Form with a chekcbox:

```
        @foreach($cforms as $candidates)                 

        <tr>  

        <td>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value= "{{$candidates->s_id}}" >

        </td>

        <td>{{$candidates->s_id}}</td>

        <td><img src="/uploads/cimage/{{ $candidates->cimage}}"   style="width:200px;height:200px;"></td>

        <td>{{$candidates->planguage}}</td> 

        <td>{{$candidates->cproject}}</td>

        <td>{{$candidates->event}}</td>

        <td>{{$candidates->docs}}</td>

        <td>{{$candidates->created_at}}</td>

        </tr>

        @endforeach

      </table></br>

{{$cforms->links()}}

     @endunless
```

Candidates Form Controller:

class cviewcontroller extends Controller
 {public function cpview(){

```
$candidates = DB::table('cforms')

              ->where('position', 'President')

              ->paginate(5); 

return view('cform.cpview', ['cforms' => $candidates]);
}
```

}

Let me know if I have to provide anything else. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.